# STN1110 LED1 keep flashing rapidly

Tags: obd, stn

I did a pcb mount for a stn1110 "Multiprotocol OBD to UART Interpreter" and followed exactly schematic from [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Widgets/stn1110-ds.pdf).

The issue I have is that after is starting, there is a sequence of flashing the 4 leds, I can see it on the serial. Sometimes I am able to send ATZ and I get answer, but after few seconds something is happening and LED1 just keep flashing rapidly and I can't get a serial connection.

Can someone tell me what means that flashing? Where I should look for the issue? 
I am sure should be something related to my pcb mount probably but have no idea how to debug this.

Comment: I doubt anyone here knows that exact chip, so what does LED1 do?

Comment: and, have you consulted the "STN1100 Family Reference and Programming Manual” referenced in the data sheet? It probably lists what these LEDs do by default and what they mean.

Comment: Is UART_RX_LED , pin 24 of the IC - https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Widgets/stn1110-ds.pdf