# STN1110 UART-RX-LED is flashing rapidly

Tags: pcb-design, obd

I did a pcb mount for a stn1110 "Multiprotocol OBD to UART Interpreter" and followed exactly schematic from [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Widgets/stn1110-ds.pdf).

The issue I have is that after is starting, there is a sequence of flashing the 4 leds, I can see on SerialtheStart Prompt "ELM327 >". Sometimes I am able to send ATZ and I get answer, but after few seconds something is happening and LED1 just keep flashing rapidly and I can't get a serial connection.

Can someone tell me what means that flashing? Where I should look for the issue? I am sure should be something related to my pcb mount probably but have no idea how to debug this.

Comment: Can you share a datasheet or schematic with us? Where does it say that 4 leds need to flash?

Comment: Heiko Schwindtner - Hi, I see that you have exactly copy & pasted [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/464401/) old, unanswered, question on the same topic. On that question, people commented with follow-up questions, but that OP didn't answer them. So, please help and [Edit] your question to show what troubleshooting you have done. For example, did you look for the document referenced in [this comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/464401/559811#comment1171264_464401) on that question? What did that reveal? Where else have you researched? Thanks.

Comment: [link](https://filehorst.de/d/dogwwfrE)  this is my schematic andthe UART-RX-LED is after 5sec flashing. the serial communication stopped also after 5sec.

Comment: the 4 leds RX TX and OBD_RX , OBD_TX is run on the start sequence for1 times. this is right